# 1 modem connect with 2 device, can it in the same network?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

My ISP provide me a moderm that has 4 input and I can plug lan cable in it

the modem model:
http://huawei.com/en/products/fixed-access/fttx/ont/hg863/index.htm

So I have attempt like this before

```
--> moderm --> router --> notebook
                      --> pc
```

it works perfectly as expected, they are in the same network.

However, recently I need to move my pc away, so I connect like this:

```
---> moderm --> router---> notebook
            --> pc
```

Although both pc and notebook can connect to internet, it no longer in the same network, any workaround to this? Thanks

Comment: Put the router in bridge mode?

Comment: I am using belkin

Comment: Belkin AC1200 Dual-Band Gigabit Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable DHCP on your router, change the router cable port from WAN port to LAN port

Comment: do you mean modem -> router is connect through one of the lan port instead of wan port? thanks

Comment: yes, just so in router view LAN1 is connecting the modem, LAN2 is connecting the PC, LAN3 is connceting the notebook, actually it doesn't matter which port to connect any device, but you must plug in LAN port instead of WAN port, the WAN port must be empty and DHCP must be disabled in your router

Comment: sorry a little confusing , then it will be router--> modem instead of modem -> router

Comment: as my modem and pc is in living room , router in my bedroom, if change like this then all 3 device need to be in living room and I can not access wireless network in bedroom. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You shouldnt switch the postition of the router and modem.  Just simply move the network cable from router WAN port to LAN port is fine

Comment: I see . As I  moved the cable from router 's wan port to one of the lan port, it just can not connect

Comment: Are you using wireless for notebook? This changes wont break wiresless function (unless you dont have strong wifi signal strength after reposition te router)

Comment: You have to disable DHCP from router,  it depends on router model,  check out the router manual if you need help

Comment: yes I have disable the dhcp server already. And also I notice there is something call ipv6 connection and there is some choice 1) auto-config/DHCP v6 (default) , 2) pppoe over IPV6, do I need to config that as well? thanks

Comment: 6to4 tunnel , pass through..

Comment: Just disable the support of ipv6 first to force using ipv4 to connect,  uncheck ipv6 from adapter option http://www.biztechmagazine.com/sites/default/files/tiny-uploads/2012/ipv6-figure1.png

Comment: my notebook is connected to router but when I switch wan to lan it just fail.  don't know the reason, is it need static ip too? Thanks your help anyway . I do more research first

Comment: Can you check does your PC can access to internet with this configuration (with wired connection) ?

Comment: the router is turning red light so it means the lan to lan connection is failure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25192/discussion-between-user782104-and-bilo).