# Router 1 device and Router 2 device is not in the same network, although router 1 connect to router 2

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

My ISP provide me a moderm hg863

the modem model:
http://huawei.com/en/products/fixed-access/fttx/ont/hg863/index.htm

So I have attempt like this before

```
---> modem --> router---> notebook
            --> pc
```

both pc and notebook can connect to internet, it is not in the same network

therefore, I found another router

```
-->modem -> router 1 -> router 2 -> notebook
                     -> pc
```

but notebook and pc are not in the same network as well. although both of them can connect to internet.

the reason why use router 2 instead of lan connect is the notebook does not have rj45 port so it need to be connect through wireless network

how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You have already asked this qestion [1 modem connect with 2 device, can it in the same network?](http://superuser.com/q/932563).. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable routing functions on the second router and therefore it will act as a wireless access point and an Ethernet switch.

This means that everything will be on the same subnet of the LAN.

Can you not replace router 1 with router 2 altogether?

Comment: one problem is after disable the wireless function,  I can only access the admin page of the router 1, instead of router 2? how to check which ip should I go to access the router 2 admin page, thanks

Comment: Router 1 will normally assign router 2 an IP address in these scenarios as it becomes a device on the network rather than a router. This can be found either by looking in the attached devices page of router 1, you can normally track it down by checking  the MAC address on the attached devices table against the MAC address on the bottom of router 2. Or you can run a simple network scanner, this can even be done from your smartphone, FING is available for free on iOS and Android.

Comment: thanks . I finally achieve it with the use of enable access point in router 2 . The only problem is the download speed seem decrease from 100mb to 70mb, is it normal? Thanks

Comment: That seems like a large decrease but it is normal to have some due to the larger overhead in sending traffic. That does however seem large but I would monitor it over time to get an average figure rather than the one you are getting right now as the networks in your area could just be busy. Glad you got it sorted, if you need anymore help let us know!